# Backward relationship in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to display data from different models in my template and I have no idea why it doesn't work properly.

Models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Location(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey('Company',
    related_name='locations')
```

Views.py:

```
def sth(request):
    loc_list = Location.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blabla/index.html', {'loc_list': loc_list})
```

Template:

```
{% for loc in loc_list %}
    {% for entry in loc.company_set.all %}
        {{entry.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Why the name of the company is not showing?

Comment: You model has the import `from django.db import models`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You foreign key relationship is the wrong way around... the way you have currently defined them, a `Location` can have only one `Company` associated with it, but in your template you are trying to fetch a list of `Company`s.

For your template logic to work, your models would have to be defined as follows:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')

class Location(models.Model):
    # You probably need some other fields in here.
```

Then this would work:

```
{% for loc in loc_list %}
    {% for entry in loc.company_set.all %}
        {{entry.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only use "_set" when accessing backwards relationships. There is no

```
loc.company_set.all
```

because each location only has one company (that is what a ForeignKey is. You can access the location's company by doing loc.company). If you want location to have multiple companies, either see solarissmoke's answer (where you put the ForeignKey attribute on Company and not on Location), or use a ManyToManyField relationship (this will allow companies to have multiple locations and each location to have multiple companies).

Then you can access all the companies of a given location by doing this in the template:

```
{% for loc in loc_list %}
    {% for entry in loc.company.all %}
        {{entry.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also access all the locations for a given company by using the related_name (company.locations).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
{% for loc in loc_list %}
     {{loc.company.name}}
{% endfor %}
```